# Passing Eval parameter to a JavaScript function from ASPX file

Tags: asp.net

I try to pass Eval value like this but get syntax errors:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnOK" OnClientClick='Show("<%#Eval("Title")%>");return false;'  runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/icon.gif" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnOK" OnClientClick='<%# Eval("Title", "Show({0});return false;") %>' runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/icon.gif" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
OnClientClick='<%#String.Format("Show('{0}');return false;",Eval("title"))%>'
```

or you if do it in the design view just add a databinding for the imagebutton's onClientClick property as

```
String.Format("Show('{0}');return false;",Eval("title"))
```

hope it helps you.