# Server Tag Issue in Gridview Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

Hello I am binding Javascript Function with Asp.net linkButton.
But i am facing the issue with calling functionality of the Javascript function.

```
function AddToDatabase(url) {
     alert(url);
}

  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn" CommandName ="sendLink" runat="server" 
       OnClientClick='javascript:AddToDatabase("' <%# Eval("myUrl") %> '")'  
        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("myUrl") %>' Text='<%# Eval("myUrl") %>'>'
          <%# Eval("myUrl") %>'</asp:LinkButton>
```

It shows me error Server tag not well formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn" CommandName ="sendLink" runat="server" 
   OnClientClick='javascript:AddToDatabase(<%# Eval("myUrl") %>)'  
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("myUrl") %>' Text='<%# Eval("myUrl") %>'>
   </asp:LinkButton>
```

### Edit 1

change OnClientClick as follows

```
  OnClientClick='<%# Eval("myUrl", "javascript:AddToDatabase({0});") %>'
```

combining both

```
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn" CommandName ="sendLink" runat="server" 
            OnClientClick='<%# Eval("myUrl", "javascript:AddToDatabase({0});") %>' 
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("myUrl") %>' Text='<%# Eval("myUrl") %>'>
  </asp:LinkButton>
```

References

[Passing Eval parameter to a JavaScript function from ASPX file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412857/passing-eval-parameter-to-a-javascript-function-from-aspx-file)

### Edit 2

Here is another link
[Passing variables to javascript in onclientclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850327/passing-variables-to-javascript-in-onclientclick)
[passing a rowindex from gridview item click to javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615886/passing-a-rowindex-from-gridview-item-click-to-javascript-function)

### Edit 3

The one which helped answerer by the @moiz

```
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn" CommandName ="sendLink" runat="server" 
        OnClientClick='<%# Eval("myUrl", "javascript:AddToDatabase(&#39;{0}&#39;);") %>' 
                 CommandArgument='<%# Eval("myUrl") %>' Text='<%# Eval("myUrl") %>'>
       '<%# Eval("myUrl") %>'
  </asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: It gives me error :  SyntaxError: syntax error
[Break On This Error]  

javascript:AddToDatabase(<%# Eval("myUrl") %>);

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error]  

javascript:AddToDatabase(http://www.google.com);

Comment: I have done that. thanks for the reply.  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn" CommandName ="sendLink" runat="server" OnClientClick='<%# Eval("myUrl", "javascript:AddToDatabase(&#39;{0}&#39;);") %>'  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("myUrl") %>' Text='<%# Eval("myUrl") %>'>'<%# Eval("myUrl") %>'</asp:LinkButton>

Comment: @Moiz I have edited my answer with some link which may help you.

Comment: Thanks shekhar. i have done that. thanks for your quick reply.